# How does the sprite of button background images in Gmail work?

Tags: javascript, css, css-sprites

Just noticed that the sprite used by Gmail for the button backgrounds in the UI is this:

[image: Gmail button background sprite]

And we all know these are the actual buttons in action:
[image: Actual Gmail buttons - WITH background images]

Until now (and even now) my idea was that the adjacent icons in that tightly packed rectangular sprite would show up in whatever background images. But there is only one icon showing in any Gmail button.
Is it just CSS? Is it JavaScript? Is it.. magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s CSS, and some "extra calories" called *nested DIVs*. The actual icon is a separate DIV positioned in the center of the button that is barely big enough to fit one icon.

Comment: Will adding such 'extra calories' to a typical web design - just to use a closely packed sprite - make it unnecessarily overweight?  
Or is it a wise choice in any case?

Answer (score 3):

### **CSS.**

They set a `background`, `height` and `width` within a `<div>` several layers deep.

If you use Chrome and right click on any of those UI buttons and click `Inspect Element`, you can see how the nested `<div>`'s are working. The HTML and CSS is a little obfuscated thanks to the way Google deploys their code, but it should be reasonably easy to understand.